# How to access class member from inner union in C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, unions

I've a small problem:

```
class A {
     public:
     enum _type {TYPE1=0,TYPE2,TYPE3} type;
     union U{
         struct _type1 {
             //somme data
         } type1;

         struct _type2 {
            //some other data
            std::vector<int> v;
         } type2;

         struct _type3 {
            // some other data
         } type3;

         U() { //constuctor
            switch(type){ // access to A::type => not accept at compile time
               case TYPE1 : /*init type1*/ break;
               case TYPE2 : /* init type2 */; new(&v) std::vector<int>; break;
               case TYPE3 : /* init type3 */ break;
               default : break;
         }

         ~U(){ //I need it to delete placement new
             switch(type)
             {
                  //same probleme
                  case TYPE2: v.~vector<int>(); break;
                  default : break;
             }
        }
     }
 };
```

the error:

> invalid use of non-static data member

As you can see, I just need to access in the union constructor to a data of the main class.
I need this to deal with "unrestricted union" (data member of the union are object in reality) so I really need to use union and not a other class.

Edit:
Finaly, I find a solution for this case:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int t); // <= add U() code here
        ~A(); // <= add ~U()  code here
    union {
        //same union data
    }; //move to anonymous union
};
```

Comment: You messed up with closing brackets: can you please correct?

Comment: Please, never use the struct name {} another_name; notation in C++. It really belongs to C and it's not modern C++ code.

Comment: Is there a (deeper) reason why you are using a union and not a base class and inheritance?  Second question: When I understood this right, the types are known at run-time and not compile-time?

Comment: @AndreasFlorath First : Yes, it's to save lot of memory, because i can't use class heritance for this case. Second : Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't physically have any "inner union" object inside your `A` objects. All you did is declare a type inside another type. This affects naming and access rights, but creates no other relationships between `A` and `U`.

If you really want to physically have an object of type `U` as a member of objects of type `A`  you have to declare a member of type `U` in class `A`. That will create a physical relationship between an `A` object and its member of type `U`. C++ language does not provide standard means for determining the address of the owner from its data member, but it can be achieved by some semi-legal hacks.

For example, if you declare

```
class A {
public:
  union U {
    ...
  };
  ...
  U u;
};
```

you will be able to gain access to the entire `A` from inside methods of `U` by doing

```
A *pa = static_cast<A *>((void *) ((char *) this - offsetof(A, u)));
```

This is obviously a rather inelegant hack, relying among other things of the hardcoded name `u` of the class member. But the technical possibility is there nevertheless.

Or you can simply pass a pointer/reference to the enveloping `A` object to the `U` object and perform access through that pointer/reference.

---

However, there's a problem of another nature specific to your example. You seem to be trying to access the owner class from *constructor* and *destructor* of a member subobject. Member subobjects are constructed *before* the owner object. And member subobjects are destructed *after* the owner object. This means that what you will see from `U`s constructor and destructor is either not yet constructed or already destructed object of type `A`. Trying to access the other members of the owner object (especially non-trivial ones) in this case is not a good idea.

Comment: `offsetof` is only applicable to PODs, otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes. This is why I call it a "hack". Although it should be noted that the OP's class is actually POD. It is me who made it non-POD by adding a non-POD member `U`.

Comment: @n.m.: In C++11 it is applicable to "standard layout" classes, which is a weaker requirement than "POD". It doesn't make things better in this case though....

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass an instance of A to the constructor, just like for anything else. The fact that the union is declared inside A is irrelevant.

Edit: You're just reinventing `boost::variant`, by the way.

Comment: Sorry but I can do this because of the destructor :/ (same probleme)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor and destructor are at the wrong place.  Move them from the union to the `class A`.

Comment: The ctor and dtor are in the right place. They more than happy to exist in a `union`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Can you please tell me how the destructor of `U` should access the `type` which is needed during destruction?

Comment: I really don't know what is happening here - but it looks that at least the idea of the wrong constructor / destructor place got into the final solution.